# How to MySQL Trigger to update a field whenever any record is touched?

Tags: mysql, datetime, triggers

I haver zero experience with triggers in MySQL. Learnt them in school (Oracle environment).

I have a table which already has a datestamp column for insert date.

I want to update a Record_Touched field whenever any record is touched in this table. What is the best efficient way of doing it?

Thank you...

Comment: Is the 'Record_Touched' field in the same table or another table?  Triggers don't work if you try to update the same table that caused the trigger.  It would work to insert a record into another table through.

Comment: It will be in the same table. So no go I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create that field as a TimeStamp and set ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

As described, I do not believe that you need a Trigger.

Comment: +1: Use the DEFAULT constraint for the desired behavior: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

Comment: I already have another column with on update current_timestamp.

I want another field and MySQL allows only one such update I believe. Thanks ...

Comment: @ThinkCode: There's no limit to the number of columns with DEFAULT constraints.